# html ejs templating and dynamic images

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

Please how do i go about displaying images whose filepath are in mongodb. i can display the images with a direct call to the image path so the image exists. however, rendering it to the browser is giving me a headache.

if i view it directly without the image tags i get the filepath.

thanks in advance for any help
below is a sample code

```
 <li class="rcontentdiv">
 <img src="<%= artiste[a].photo.data %>" 
 class="dipimg"/></li>
```

when i do this and load the browser i get the below error

`GET /uploads/artisteImage-1516934971663.png 404`